# Getting location from another file using Promise in react native with react-native-geolocation-service

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, geolocation

I'm trying to make a helper function to get the current location of the user, but the result of my promise is undefined.

This function is working and I can retrieve my coordinates :

```
//position.js

async function getCurrentPosition() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 15000,
      maximumAge: 10000,
    });
  });
}

export async function getUserLocation() {
  await request(
    // Check for permissions
    Platform.select({
      android: PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
      ios: PERMISSIONS.IOS.LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE,
    }),
  ).then((res) => {
    console.log('then');
    // Permission OK
    if (res === 'granted') {
      console.log('granted');
      return getCurrentPosition();
      // Permission denied
    } else {
      console.log('Location is not enabled');
    }
  });
}
```

But when I call my function here, I get undefined :

```
import {getUserLocation} from '../../utils/position';

useEffect(() => {
    getUserLocation()
      .then((res) => console.log(res)) // { undefined }
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err.message);
      });
  }, []);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using strings first like "Resolved" and "Rejected" also add your Geolocation.getCurrentPosition inside try and catch block

Comment: I tried what you said but still have undefined, even if  I try to pass strings instead of position.coords

Comment: What platform you use ?And real device or simulator ? because your code worked with my android simulator and returned a location.

Comment: IOS emulator. But I can also get a location within the getCurrentPosition() function, but when I called it in my use effect (in another file), I can't get the resolve values. There :

.then((res) => console.log(res)) // { undefined }

Comment: As written, `getUserLocation()` does not return its `request(...).then()` promise. Change `await` to `return`.

Comment: Also, you should really change `console.log('Location is not enabled');` to `throw new Error('Location is not enabled')`, thus allowing getUserLocation's caller to see the error (should it arise).

Comment: Oh yes thank you, that's it! I was struggling with promises. 
Do you want to make an answer to my post or I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, getUserLocation() does not return its request(...).then() promise. Change `await` to `return`.

Also, you should really change `console.log('Location is not enabled')` to `throw new Error('Location is not enabled')`, thus allowing getUserLocation's caller to see the error (should it arise).

```
export async function getUserLocation() {
    return request(Platform.select({ // Check for permissions
 // ^^^^^^
        'android': PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        'ios': PERMISSIONS.IOS.LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE
    }))
    .then((res) => {
        if (res === 'granted') { // Permission OK
            return getCurrentPosition();
        } else { // Permission denied
            throw new Error('Location is not enabled'); // Throwing an Error here
                                                        // makes it available to the caller
                                                        // in its catch clause.
        }
    });
}
```